# NestJS Endpoint flow mapping

Tags: nest

I have an API in NestJS, which uses the Controller > Services > Repositories simple architecture.

However, in this environment, I have several services that are called only once, directly by a controller. And I have other services that are intermediary, that is, they are not called directly by the controllers (but sometimes can be), but are called by several other services, making them being part of the flow of several controllers, indirectly. The same goes for repositories.

I would like to know if there`s a tool that could give me a mapping/diagram of every flow of an endpoint/controller, seeing all the services it calls and all the services those services call.

Something ready to show me every flow, or how can i input an class method (controller) and it show me which other class methods it calls (services) and goes on on it till end.

I would like to have an output like that:

[image]

See, that is a diagram, that shows 2 flows, and show me that one method (repositoryFindUser) its being called by two services, making it part of 2 different flows (update and find user).

Being done all by a ready to use tool, or something that just map the code for me and i create the diagrams, could work for me also.

Im Expecting a tool to map my code and show me all method calls in a diagram, or just show me the calls, something that makes me can visualize all flows and multiple calls and participations of methods in several flows.